# Showing a branch which i not even there in Github

Tags: github

The repo have only one branch(i.e, main) is also the default one but while opening the files it is showing a branch name '**b3c52f83e0**'.

What's the issue?

[image: GitHub screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It would be not the name of a branch, but a SHA1 of a commit.

Check your GitHub project commits history and see if that commit does exist.
You cal also check that locally by cloning the same repository, and using  `git log`.